# Are there alternative methods for installing Video4Linux (v4l) and Linux DVB (DVB) drivers for RHEL 9?

Tags: drivers, video, rocky-linux

In RHEL 9, Video4Linux (v4l) and Linux DVB (DVB) devices television and video capture devices are no longer supported. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/9.0_release_notes/deprecated_functionality#deprecated-functionality_kernel

On Oracle Linux 8.8

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/media
cec     dvb-core       firewire  mmc  radio  tuners  v4l2-core
common  dvb-frontends  i2c       pci  rc     usb
```

On Rocky Linux 9.2

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/media
cec  common  mc  usb  v4l2-core
```

Are there alternative methods for installing these drivers for RHEL 9?

Comment: what is the business related question or issue in here?